# web service implementation class method invocation

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am trying to implement a Web Service Server in Java based Framework.
I have generated Java classes from the WSDL.
I have a basic doubt in the 'Service Implementation Class' that is implemented for the Web Service Interface.

What I understand is when my Service gets a request, it is this implementation class which has the overridden methods from the interface, that must get invoked for request handling.
But I do not understand how are they invoked ?
What mechanism takes care of invoking the specific web method from the implementation class, corresponding to SOAP request I get from Client ?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jws20/ please follow above link

Comment: Also, why does "The implementing class must have a default public constructor." ?

Comment: are you using axis2 for implementing soap ?

Comment: No, I used an Ant script that uses "wsimport" tool to generate the java classes. Since with axis2 I did not get annotations I expected for the service classes.

Comment: what I understand is you need to know once you add service with the client then how stubs classes generates and request work with the wsdl isn't ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to read about it a lot, and I have been able to  generate stub classes from wsdl with correct WebService annotations. Now, from the generated Service Interface I implemented the Service Implementation Class and overrided the web methods. I want to know how its methods ( annotated 'WebMethod' ) are called. I assume, it is the framework that takes care of mapping request to the implemented class, however is my understanding right ?

Comment: ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jws20 please follow above link you get some idea how wsdl works.once you importing the any wsdl (Web Services Description Language. WSDL) that is  XML message from your service vendor and client. Now  the Thing is how is generate the java classes which you are able to use in your business Logic. It may happen by the xml notation bind with the wsdl url or file and once your add it with your project then the that messages is parse by your frame work and do the all invocation and execution it self.

Comment: Like in past we have RMI which is best example to understand the basic methodology of web services (in JAVA context).

Comment: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.webservice.doc%2Ftopics%2Fjaxws%2Ftsklwsdljaxws.html this link is also help full.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and links above. It definitely helped to understand wsdl and related java bean components. :)

Comment: any time @Prajakta :). I glade to help you.